# mysql query "not in"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM `photo` p where 4 not in (2,4,5)
```

from the query it is not show anything because there is 4.
but why if we query

```
SELECT * FROM `photo` p where 4 not in (user_view)
```

table photo:

```
photo ID | user_view
1        | 2,3,4,5
```

it is still show the record. why the code is not running well if we use not in from the database field?

how to make the same function with

```
SELECT * FROM `photo` p where 4 not in (2,4,5)
```

I want to show the record only if the photo is haven't see by user. So it will show uniquely by user who don't have an ID in user_view.thanks

Comment: the problem is your database structure. you should normalise it

Comment: This question has been asked before; someone more motivated than I am will flag this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column `user_view` is a comma delimited list like it seems to be, you can use the built-in FIND_IN_SET function:

```
 SELECT * FROM `photo` p where FIND_IN_SET(4, `user_view`) != 0
```

This will check if the input '4' exists as one of the items in the `user_view` column and return the index number if found and 0 if not.

Answer (score 0):

A column storing a comma separated list is a single value. It's just a single string value that happens to contain comma characters.

Those commas are *not* considered to be part of the SQL text.

When you do this is a:

```
  foo NOT IN ( 2 , 4 , 5 )
```

MySQL sees that as three separate values, the commas are part of the SQL text; that's equivalent to

```
  ( foo <> 2 AND foo <> 4 AND foo <> 5 )
```

When you do this:

```
  foo NOT IN ( '2,4,5' )
```

That's equivalent to:

```
  foo <> '2,4,5'
```

(In MySQL, in a numeric context, the string literal is going to evaluate as a numeric value of 2.)

---

If you are asking how to "fix" this *without* changing your database  (and storing comma separated lists *is* a SQL anti-pattern)

You could do this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM `photo` p 
 WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(4,p.user_view)
```

Or, you could do this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM `photo` p 
  WHERE CONCAT(',',p.user_view,',') NOT LIKE '%,4,%'
```